# Lab 10.1: computer science assignment

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, printing, system.out

In case I haven't already asked about this one, here are the instructions, as always:

The `int t` contains an integer between 1 and 50 (inclusive). Write code that outputs the
    number in words and stores the result in the String inwords. For example, if t is 35 then
    inwords should contain "thirty five".

Here is my code:

```
int t = ; 
String inwords;
String[] Numbers = 49;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    if (i % 10 = 0)
    if (i / 10 == 1)
            System.out.println("ten")
        else if (i / 10 == 2)
            System.out.println("twenty")
        else if (i / 10 == 3)
            System.out.println("thirty")
        else if (i / 10 == 4)
            System.out.println("
}
```

What I'm assuming is the issue is that I don't have a way of short-cutting it. I may be wrong but is there more of an implementable pattern than I already see? I know my code isn't complete, but I need to know if there's a pattern I'm not seeing here. I mean, how would I implement it if I already find myself typing out every single division sign. You saw how long that code was getting didn't you?

All help appreciated

PS, hope I'm not asking too much about my school labs.

Comment: I take my comment back. Refactor your code properly before we can discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could go about it...

1. Transform the number into a string, and check its length.
2. If you have a string length of 2, then you know that you will have 2 words in your number, with the exception of the number 10.

   a.  You check to see what the string is, and you append the appropriate word (ten, twenty, etc).

   b.  You then move to the next number in the string, and you append the equivalent to the string (one, two, etc).
3. If on the other hand, you have 1 digit, then you just repeat step 2b.

This approach needs some thinking when dealing with numbers ranging from 10 to 12, but it should do what you need.

Also, I do not know if your examples is how you code, but you need to place `{` and `}` after if statements in Java, so: `if(boolean){ your logic }`. Not using curly braces after `if` statements will only make the first statement execute.